# What is best way to get breakdown image in UIImage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

for example : if i have one image of man, 
and i want to trigger event from different part of human body (from head, stomach).

So What is best way to make that image and trigger pro-grammatically from UIImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution by this one:

I have slice images of different regions with same size, 
and arrange it like one images. 
Now on click i have just check that on image clicked done....

This is code for that...

```
    -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
     {

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];

BOOL alphaFace = [self isPointTransparent:point addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"face.png"]];
BOOL alphaHand = [self isPointTransparent:point addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hand.png"]];
BOOL alphaMidStomach = [self isPointTransparent:point addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"midStomach.png"]];
NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"beep" ofType:@"wav"];;
NSURL *fileURL= [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];;

    if(alphaFace)
    {
        // Clicked on Face Image
    }
    else if(alphaHand)
    {
        // Clicked on Hand Image
    }
    else if(alphaMidStomach)
    {
        // Clicked on Stomach Image
    }
    // Now just check alplha , if it's No then do something....

 }   
  -CGContextRef CreateARGBBitmapContext (CGImageRef inImage)
  {
CGContextRef    context = NULL;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = NULL; // tell we want  kCGImageAlphaOnly
void *          bitmapData;
int             bitmapByteCount;
int             bitmapBytesPerRow;


size_t pixelsWide = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
size_t pixelsHigh = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);
bitmapBytesPerRow   = (pixelsWide * 1); // 8bpp
bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

bitmapData = calloc(1, bitmapByteCount );
if (bitmapData == NULL) 
{
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
    return nil;
}
context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                 pixelsWide,
                                 pixelsHigh,
                                 8,
                                 bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                 colorSpace,
                                 kCGImageAlphaOnly);
if (context == NULL)
{
    free (bitmapData);
    fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
}
CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );

return context;
  }

 - (NSData *) ARGBData:(UIImage*)image  {
CGContextRef cgctx = CreateARGBBitmapContext(image.CGImage);
if (cgctx == NULL) 
    return nil;

size_t w = CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage);
size_t h = CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage);
CGRect rect = {{0,0},{w,h}}; 
CGContextDrawImage(cgctx, rect, image.CGImage); 

unsigned char *data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);
CGContextRelease(cgctx); 
if (!data)
    return nil;

size_t dataSize = 1 * w * h; // 8 bits

return [NSData dataWithBytes:data length:dataSize];
 }

 -(BOOL) isPointTransparent: (CGPoint) point addImage:(UIImage*)image {
NSData *rawData = [self ARGBData:image];  // Or cache this
if (rawData == nil)
    return NO;

// just 8 bits per alpha component
size_t bpp = 1;
size_t bpr = 320 * 1;

NSUInteger index = (point.x * bpp) + (point.y * bpr);
unsigned char *rawDataBytes = (unsigned char *)[rawData bytes];

return rawDataBytes[index] == 0;    
}
```

Comment: Hey brijesh i have a map and want to show region name which i clicked then can i use this method?

Comment: Ya sure, for that, You have to create image with different region all with same size, apart from the region part in image will be transparent. then You have to use above code same with map.

Answer (score 1):

I would figure out the regions of the image that you want to trigger different events and then use either a *UIGestureRecoginzer* or an override of the "touches" methods of *UIView* to determine whether a touch has fallen within one of these regions. You would then need to determine if the location of a touch is within the regions you've defined using a 2D point-in-shape-test ([here's a really good example of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test)). This test could be more complicated depending on the complexity of the regions you've defined.